# How can I make my local mysql settings match Amazon RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a setup where I develop locally using a local mysql instance and then I push my code to AWS, which uses an RDS MySQL instance.

I want to make my local database match RDS settings as closely as possible. I run into configuration problems, where an obvious issue does not exhibit itself in local development, but my tests fail on RDS. For example, one recent issue was that the RDS default charset for tables is latin1 whereas the default settings for brew-installed mysql is UTF-8.

I can solve these problems as they occur, but it would be really useful to do a bulk-setup that configures my local MySQL to match RDS as much as possible.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go into the parameter group you are using in RDS and copy all those settings to your local MySQL server.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I'm trying to figure out how to download the parameter group. I can do `aws rds describe-db-parameters --db-parameter-group-name <group>` but it only gives schema, not values...

Comment: Any reason you can't just view it in the web console and copy the values?

Comment: Hi Mark, I can view in the web UI but I want to translate its full config to a my.cnf I can use locally. I also want to make this a repeatable process. Not really tenable by copying and pasting values manually from a web UI.

Comment: It doesn't just return the "schema", you will have a "ParameterValue" attribute if a value has been set for the given property. There are lots of values that are empty or "unset" by default, in which case they are just using the MySQL defaults.

Comment: Mark, thanks a lot, I see now that on most properties the value is missing. I wrote a script to generate a my.cnf from these values, thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi Marius, I'm curious if that script is on github. I'd love to see how it works!

Comment: @Marius, seconding the request for the script...that would be helpful!

Comment: @Marius I'm interested in your script as well. You haven(t published it on Github it seems :-( https://github.com/mariusnita?tab=overview

Answer (score 3):

The [aws cli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) can be used to retrieve your RDS configuration. The command I used to pull it down is below. Replace `YOUR_PARAMETER_GROUP_NAME` with your RDS parameter group name and the `--source` can be `system`, `user` or `engine-default` (or remove the `--source` argument and it will retrieve them all). The below command uses [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) as well.

```
aws rds describe-db-parameters --db-parameter-group-name YOUR_PARAMETER_GROUP_NAME --source system | jq -r '.Parameters[] | (.ParameterName + "=" + .ParameterValue)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short powershell command (based on the suggested answer) to retrieve all the non-default parameters for a specified parameter group (replace "default.mysql-57" with the specific parameter group name you are using):

```
Get-RDSDBParameter -DBParameterGroupName default.mysql5.7 | 
  select ParameterName, ParameterValue |
  where {$_.ParameterValue -ne $null}
```